# Universal Properties and Equalizer

Tags: category-theory

Good evening. At the moment I am looking into category theory and at the moment I am trying to proof the Universal Property of the kernel as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28category_theory%29). I use the definition that the kernel of $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is the equalizer of $f$ and the zero-morphism from $X$ to $Y$. Using [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Equalizer.html) definition of the equalizer it shouldn't be too hard but what peeked my interest is if this definition is the actual definition of the equaliser or if it is auniversal property? Or are universal properties definitions in category theory?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you define the kernel as the equalizer of $f$ and $0$, and you want to prove that for any morphism $g:K'\to X$ such that $fg=0$, there is a unique morphism $u:K'\to K$ such that $ku=g$? But this is almost trivial, using the fact that the zero morphism composed with $g$ is the zero morphism.

Comment: Well yes but that should follow directly from the definition of the equalizer. My question ist if the definition is one of the foundations of Universal Properties (I mean, you need to start somewhere with commutative diagrams in definitions) or if it is a universal property. The third option would be if  universal properties are definitions in category theory

Comment: That is the actual definition of equalizer, it includes the universal property. It is quite common in category theory to define something using a universal property. For instance, an equalizer is a particular case of a limit, which is defined by a universal property.