# Universal properties of kernel and equalizer

Tags: category-theory, modules, universal-property

> The following diagram of $R$-modules is commutative.
>   $\require{AMScd}$
>   \begin{CD}
>     M @>f>> P\\
>     @VVgV @VV\varphi V\\
>     Q @>\psi>> N
> \end{CD}
>   Prove: $M$ is the pullback of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ $\iff$ $0\to M\xrightarrow{(f,g)}P\oplus Q\xrightarrow{\varphi-\psi}N$ is exact.

My try:

$\boxed{\Leftarrow}$ Let $T$ be a $R$-module and $(s,t):T\mapsto P\oplus Q$ such that $(\varphi-\psi)\circ (s,t)=0$. We want to prove that there exists a unique map $h:T\to M$ such that $(f,g)\circ h=(s,t)$.

From the exactness of the sequence, we have $(\varphi-\psi)\circ (f,g)=0$. ($\star$) (Also, it seems strange that I don't use that the sequence is exact at $M$..)

$\boxed{\Rightarrow}$ I have no idea how to handle this direction.

($\star$) I now want to invoke the [universal property of the kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(category_theory)) to prove the existence of such $h$. However, in my syllabus, this universal property is not written down. However, my syllabus states the [universal property of the equalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equaliser_(mathematics)#In_category_theory) and shows that in the case of $R$-modules, the kernel of a $R$-module homomorphism $f:R\to S$ is an equalizer.

I would like to know if it is possible to deduce the universal property from the other one, or if there is an easy direct proof of the universal property of the kernel. I think there is one, but I have been working on this problem for too long and I can't seem to see it. (I am aware of 
[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231697/universal-properties-and-equalizer), but it has no concrete answer.)

---

*Edit.*

In my syllabus, it is proved that the equalizer of $f:X\to Y$ and the zero map is the kernel of $f$. Let $\iota:\operatorname{Ker} f\to X$ be the inclusion map. The universal property of the equalizer now gives:

For every morphism $t:T\to X$ such that $ft=0$, there exists a unique morphism $h:T\to \operatorname{Ker}f$ such that $\iota h=t$.

I want to apply this to be above exercise. We have $(\varphi-\psi)\circ (s,t)=0$ and $(\varphi-\psi)\circ (f,g)=0$, where $(s,t):T\to P\oplus Q$ and $(f,g):M\to P\oplus Q$. Applying the above gives unique morphisms $h_1:T\to \operatorname{Ker}(\varphi-\psi)$ and $h_2:M\to \operatorname{Ker}(\varphi-\psi)$ such that stuff commutes. But what I want is a morphism $T\to M$..

Comment: Hi! The idea is that $\ker(f)$ is the equalizer of the maps $f,0:R\rightarrow S$. If you now try to write down the universal property of the equalizer $eq(f,0)$ you obtain the universal property of kernel

Comment: @rae306, Hint: prove firstly that $(\ker(\varphi-\psi),\pi_P,\pi_Q)$ is the pullback of $(\varphi,\psi)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in the comments by *Menezio* the kernel a map $f\colon M\to N$ is the equalizer of $f$ and the trivial map $0$. This is a natural requirement as we expect from the kernel that every element $x\in\ker f$ is taken to the $0$-element in $N$ after pre-composing with the inclusion $\iota\colon\ker f\to M$. Equivalently arrow-wise: we expect $f\circ\iota=0$, i.e. that pre-composing with $\iota$ equals the trivial map.

Now, the equaliser ${\rm eq}(f,0)$ consist of an object $\ker f$ and a map $\iota\colon\ker f\to M$ such that $f\circ\iota=0\circ\iota=0$ (as composing with the trivial map is always trivial) and is universal as such. That is, for every map $k\colon K\to M$ with $f\circ k=0~\circ k=0$ there exists an unqiue map $\tilde k\colon K\to\ker f$ such that $\iota\circ\tilde k=k$.
To put it otherwise: the kernel of a map $f\colon M\to N$ is universal among maps $g\colon K\to M$ such that $f\circ g=0$, which might sound like the more usual definition. Explicitly

> The kernel of $f\colon M\to N$ is the unique par $(\ker f,\iota)$, where $\iota:\ker f\to M$ and $f\circ\iota=0$. This pair is universal in so far that for every $f\circ g=0$, with $g\colon K\to M$, there exists a unique $\tilde g\colon K\to\ker f$ such that $\iota\circ\tilde g=g$.

Comment: I understand everything in your answer. However, it seems to me that the universal property of the kernel on the Wikipedia page is slightly more general? It says the following: if $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism, we call kernel an object $K$ together with a morphism $k:K\to X$ such that (1) $f\circ k=0$ and (2) for all $k':K'\to X$ with $f\circ k'=0$, there exists a unique morphism $u:K\to K'$ such that $k\circ u=k'$.

Comment: I think we need this more general version to solve the problem, since the above only gives two morphisms $T \to \operatorname{ker}(\phi-\psi)$ and $M\to \operatorname{ker}(\phi-\psi)$ and not a morphism $T\to M$.

Comment: @rae306 How does this one differ from the one I gave? To be fair, I did not explictly wrote it down as kernel-universal-property but phrased in its equaliser formulation. But this is precisely what you wrote.

Comment: I added a comment above.. it is with respect to the problem I am solving.

Comment: @rae306 I have read the comments multiple times and I can still not figure out what is missing in the universal property of the kernel I gave; could you elaborate on how you would use the Wikipedia version to solve the exercise and point out where my version is insufficient?

Comment: Yes of course, I am going to edit my question right away. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @rae306 If I am not mistaken: as the given sequence is exact, in fact ${\rm im}(g,h)=\ker(\varphi-\psi)$ and therefore I think $h_2=(g,h)=\iota$ already. Exactness at $M$ implies that $(g,h)$ is monic which agress with $\iota$ being monic.

Comment: Do you mean the following? We obtain a unique morphism $h_1:T\to {\rm ker}(\varphi-\psi)$. Now, by exactness, ${\rm ker}(\varphi-\psi)={\rm im}(f,g)$. By exactness and the first isomorphism theorem, $M/{\rm ker}(f,g)=M\xrightarrow{\sim}{\rm im} (f,g)$, hence we have a (unique) morphism $T\to M$ by composing?

Comment: @rae306 Yes. And this would also use exactness at both componentes.

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks! Could you also give a hand for the other direction of the implication? (Should that one be the easier one..?)

Comment: @rae306 Two things: first off, I am not experienced with pullbacks, so I would have to think about this for a while too. Second, maybe this is better suited for another thread (after making some attempts and showing how far you got) as this question is more or less specifically about deducing the universal property of the kernel.

Comment: @rae306 Were you able to finish the exercise on your own? Also, is there anything I can do to improve my answer?

Comment: I will accept your answer :) I spent hours and hours on this problem and I am still not satisfied about my solution, but that's another problem

Comment: @rae306 Thank you kindly. Maybe consider asking another question with the tag "solution-verification" to spot mistakes in your own solution (if there are any). Anyway, good luck!